# Scaling Django storage on webfaction

Tags: django, amazon-s3, webfaction, django-storage

I launched a website a month ago that allows users to upload pictures. The site is taking off and I could be out of my 200 GB of space on webfaction in 2 or 3 months.

What is the best solution to scale? Is it Amazon S3? or should I look into other hosts?

If the best option is Amazon S3, do you recommend migrating the uploaded files on local server with a script everyday or using django-storage(currently not even installed)? What are the cons and pros? Please note the fact that I've already launched and I also perform some manipulation such as creating thumbnails after a file is uploaded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offload your static storage to somewhere with more space.  Your static files storage needn't be on the same server as the django installation.  Also consider how you're using disk space.  If you don't desparately need full resolution images, consider down-resing them.  200GB will cost you lots wherever you go.